# angularjs i am using multiple select tag how to clear its all option after saved in db

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to clear multiple select option after saving into DB, i am using ng-model to clear it. Its clearing in back-end but not in UI side. 
In controller I am writing:

```
smsType = {};
smsType.smsTypeId = [];
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="form-group">
 <select ng-model="smsType.smsTypeId" ui-jq="chosen" multiple
    class="w-md"
    ng-options="s.id as s.name for s in smsoption.name">
 </select>
</div>
```

Its not reflecting in ui side

Please give me some suggestion i am new to angularjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see demo below

you missed $scope here

```
smsType.smsTypeId = [];
```

should be

```
$scope.smsType.smsTypeId = [];
```

```js
// Code goes here
angular.module("myApp", []);

angular.module("myApp").controller("SelectCtrl", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {
    $scope.smsoption = {
      name: [{
        "id": "122",
        "name": "denmark"
      }, {
        "id": "123",
        "name": "france"
      }, {
        "id": "124",
        "name": "italy"
      }]
    };

    $scope.saveit = function() {
      console.log($scope.selectCenter);
      $scope.smsType.smsTypeId = [];
    }
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<h1>ngOption demo</h1>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="SelectCtrl">

    <select ng-model="smsType.smsTypeId" ui-jq="chosen" multiple class="w-md" ng-options="s.id as s.name for s in smsoption.name">
    </select>
    <hr/>You have chosen:
    <span ng-repeat="type in smsType.smsTypeId">{{type}} | </span>
    <button ng-click="saveit()">Save</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but i am doing same thing its not working i forgot to add $scope here but in my code i already added. Can you give me some suggestion.

Comment: i removed this attribute : ui-jq="chosen" now its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

The model is the output, not the input. To clear it you need to clear smsoption. The model should reflect the options you have selected, not the other way around.

`smsoption = [];`

Should do it

Comment: Thanks for reply, i don't want to clear the array, after saving also the options should be there but not as selected.

Comment: Well, I know this is a bit of a hack, but you could switch to an empty array, and then switch back, maybe after a setTimeout(func, 0)? That should solve your immediate problem of wanting to deselect the values.